# In place real to complex FFT with cufft

Tags: c++, cuda, cufft

I am trying to perform an inplace real to complex FFT with cufft.
I am aware of the similar question [How to perform a Real to Complex Transformation with cuFFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240591/how-to-perform-a-real-to-complex-transformation-with-cufft). However I have issues trying to reproduce the same method.

If I do an out of place transformation, there is no problem, but as soon as I do it in place, I do not have the correct values in the FFT (Checked with python, using binary files in between). I do not have errors, but just non correct values.

Here is my code:

```
void fftCuda2d(mat3d* scene)
{
    cufftResult resultStatus;
    cudaError_t cuda_status;

    cufftHandle plan_forward;

    resultStatus = cufftPlan2d(&plan_forward, scene->_height, scene->_width, CUFFT_R2C);
    cout << "Creating plan forward: " << _cudaGetErrorEnum(resultStatus) << endl;

    cufftComplex *d_fft, *d_scene, *h_fft;

    size_t size_fft = (int(scene->_width/2)+1)*scene->_height;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_scene, sizeof(cufftComplex)*size_fft);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_fft, sizeof(cufftComplex)*size_fft);


    h_fft = (cufftComplex*) malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex)*size_fft);

    cuda_status = cudaMemcpy(d_scene, scene->_pData, sizeof(cufftReal) * scene->_height * scene->_width, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    resultStatus = cufftExecR2C(plan_forward, (cufftReal*) d_scene, d_scene);

    cuda_status = cudaMemcpy(h_fft, d_scene, sizeof(cufftReal)*scene->_height*scene->_width, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    FILE* *pFileTemp;

    pFileTemp = fopen("temp.bin", "wb");

    check = fwrite(h_fft, sizeof(cufftComplex), sizeFft, pFileTemp);

}
```

If I use `resultStatus = cufftExecR2C(plan_forward, (cufftReal*) d_scene, d_fft);` and save the output of `d_fft` I have the correct result.
So you see any mistake of mine here?

P.S Mat3d is a struct where _width and _height contain the size of the matrix and pData is the pointer to the data but there is no issue with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(It seems like this should be a duplicate question but I was not able to locate the duplicate.)

Your input data needs to be organized differently (padded) when using an in-place transform.  This is particularly noticeable in the 2D case, because each row of data must be padded.

In the non-inplace R2C transform, the input data is real-valued and of size height*width (for an example R=4, C=4 case):

```
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
```

The above data would occupy exactly `16*sizeof(cufftReal)` (assuming `float` input data, dimension R = 4, C = 4), **and it would be organized that way in memory, linearly, with no gaps**.  However, when we switch to an in-place transform, the size of the input buffer changes.  And this change in size has ramifications for data arrangement.  Specifically, the sizeof the input buffer is `R*(C/2 + 1)*sizeof(cufftComplex)`.  For the R=4, C=4 example case, that is `12*sizeof(cufftComplex)` or `24*sizeof(cufftReal)`, but it is still organized as 4 rows of data.  Each row, therefore, is of length 6 (if measured in `cufftReal`) or 3 (if measured in `cufftComplex`).  Considering it as `cufftReal`, then when we create our input data, we must organize it like this:

```
X X X X P P
X X X X P P
X X X X P P
X X X X P P
```

where the `P` locations are "padding" data, not your input data.  If we view this linearly in memory, it looks like:

```
X X X X P P X X X X P P X X X X P P X X X X P P
```

[That is the expectation/requirement of CUFFT](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#data-layout) (and I believe it is the same for FFTW). However since you made no changes to the way you deposited your data, you provided data that looks like this:

```
X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X P P P P P P P P
```

and the difference in those 2 patterns is what accounts for the difference in the result output.  There are a variety of ways to fix this.  I'll choose to demonstrate using [`cudaMemcpy2D`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g3a58270f6775efe56c65ac47843e7cee) to populate the device input buffer in the in-place case, which will give us the desired pattern.  This may not be the best/fastest way, depending on your application needs.

You were also not copying the correct size of the result data from device back to host.

Here is a fixed example:

```
$ cat t1589.cu
#include <cufft.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct mat3d{
  int _width;
  int _height;
  cufftReal *_pData;
};


void fftCuda2d(mat3d* scene)
{
    cufftResult resultStatus;
    cudaError_t cuda_status;

    cufftHandle plan_forward;

    resultStatus = cufftPlan2d(&plan_forward, scene->_height, scene->_width, CUFFT_R2C);
    std::cout << "Creating plan forward: " <<  (int)resultStatus << std::endl;

    cufftComplex *d_fft, *d_scene, *h_fft;

    size_t size_fft = (int(scene->_width/2)+1)*scene->_height;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_scene, sizeof(cufftComplex)*size_fft);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_fft, sizeof(cufftComplex)*size_fft);


    h_fft = (cufftComplex*) malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex)*size_fft);

#ifdef USE_IP
    cuda_status = cudaMemcpy2D(d_scene, ((scene->_width/2)+1)*sizeof(cufftComplex), scene->_pData, (scene->_width)*sizeof(cufftReal), sizeof(cufftReal) * scene->_width, scene->_height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    resultStatus = cufftExecR2C(plan_forward, (cufftReal*) d_scene, d_scene);
    cuda_status = cudaMemcpy(h_fft, d_scene, sizeof(cufftComplex)*size_fft, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
#else
    cuda_status = cudaMemcpy(d_scene, scene->_pData, sizeof(cufftReal) * scene->_height * scene->_width, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    resultStatus = cufftExecR2C(plan_forward, (cufftReal*) d_scene, d_fft);
    cuda_status = cudaMemcpy(h_fft, d_fft, sizeof(cufftComplex)*size_fft, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
#endif
    std::cout << "exec: " <<  (int)resultStatus << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size_fft; i++)
      std::cout << h_fft[i].x << " " << h_fft[i].y << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
const int dim = 4;
int main(){

  mat3d myScene;
  myScene._pData  = new cufftReal[dim*dim];
  myScene._width  = dim;
  myScene._height = dim;
  for (int i = 0; i < dim*dim; i++) myScene._pData[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
  fftCuda2d(&myScene);
  std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()) << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -lineinfo -o t1589 t1589.cu -lcufft
t1589.cu(15): warning: variable "cuda_status" was set but never used

$ ./t1589
Creating plan forward: 0
exec: 0
9.71338 0,-0.153554 1.45243,0.171302 0,0.878097 0.533959,0.424595 -0.834714,0.858133 -0.393671,-0.205139 0,-0.131513 -0.494514,-0.165712 0,0.878097 -0.533959,0.0888268 1.49303,0.858133 0.393671,
no error
$ nvcc -lineinfo -o t1589 t1589.cu -lcufft -DUSE_IP
t1589.cu(15): warning: variable "cuda_status" was set but never used

$ ./t1589
Creating plan forward: 0
exec: 0
9.71338 0,-0.153554 1.45243,0.171302 0,0.878097 0.533959,0.424595 -0.834714,0.858133 -0.393671,-0.205139 0,-0.131513 -0.494514,-0.165712 0,0.878097 -0.533959,0.0888268 1.49303,0.858133 0.393671,
no error
$
```